# Logging user responses for IBM Watson Chatbot

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to implement IBM Watson chatbot into a mobile application, and would need logging of user responses to the chatbot. So far, I don't know of any docs or guides to log user responses to the chatbot or the chatbot's responses.

How would I log the user's messages to the bot?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "logging responses to the bot"? Do you mean sending the user input to the bot and receiving the answer?

Comment: Yes, and recording the answer.

Comment: If you develop your own bot user interface, you could then send either the customer question or question and answer to a DB. There are a number of examples around this type of action, @data_henrik has created a few in the past. Or you could use the Watson Assistant API's to pull the logs of the conversation and store those as a separate process, a cloud function on a daily timer, which pulls the logs and stores them into a DB is what I have utilised in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start investigating the [docs about the Watson Assistant API](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-overview). They are part of the Watson Assistant documentation and describe how to integrate a bot (assistant + skill(s)) into an app.

Watson Assistant provides several ready integrations to link an assistant to platforms like Facebook Messenger, Slack, Zenhub and others. But for a custom application you would need to use the API. The [Watson Developer Cloud org on GitHub](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/) hosts SDKs for many common programming languages, including code samples.